# jQuery don't work well with Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I found a clock plugin on the Internet, but it doesn't work with IE8. Why?

Code: http://solutionsbr.uphero.com/projeto/

***JavaScript Code***

```
       $(function() {                                         

            if ($("#sec").length > 0) {
                setInterval(function() {
                    var seconds = new Date().getSeconds();
                    var sdegree = seconds * 6;
                    var srotate = "rotate(" + sdegree + "deg)";
                    $("#sec").css("transform", srotate);

                }, 1000);
            }

            if ($("#hour").length > 0) {
                setInterval(function() {
                    var hours = new Date().getHours();
                    var mins = new Date().getMinutes();
                    var hdegree = hours * 30 + (mins / 2);
                    var hrotate = "rotate(" + hdegree + "deg)";
                    $("#hour").css("transform", hrotate);

                }, 1000);
            }

            if ($("#min").length > 0) {
                setInterval(function() {
                    var mins = new Date().getMinutes();
                    var mdegree = mins * 6;
                    var mrotate = "rotate(" + mdegree + "deg)";
                    $("#min").css("transform", mrotate);
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
```

***Solution***

Use another WebBrowser, the rotate property of IE8 sucks. If someone need more information about that, look here [Internet Explorer 8 Rotate](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/28/css3-solutions-for-internet-explorer/).

Comment: Because IE8 sucks and should be banned to anyone outside North Korea.

Comment: Because you use a webkit style, IE is not webkit `-webkit-transform: rotate(436.5deg);` [Look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj127312(v=vs.85).aspx#code-snippet-1)

Comment: @Bondye the script uses the transform suitable for the browser. For IE it uses the according IE transform.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to use rotate value for transform css property which is not supported for IE version under 9